# Error when using Principle Component Analysis with Point Clouds in ROS?

Tags: c++, ros, pca, point-clouds, pcl

I would like to use PCA on the point clouds to find the lane . So the Principle Component Analysis should work fine for this problem. So Im not sure how to correctly use PCA with Point Clouds and ROS.
Here is the code that I create so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include <vector> 
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud.h>
#include <laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <pcl/common/pca.h>

using namespace std;

laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;
tf::TransformListener listener_;

void getOrientation (const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan)

{
    //convert laser scan into point clouds
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud cloud;
    projector_.projectLaser(*scan, cloud);

    //Construct a buffer used by the pca analysis
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud_projected, cloud_reconstructed;
    pcl::PointXYZ projected, reconstructed;
    pcl::PCA<pcl::PointXYZ> pca;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < cloud.points.size(); i++)
    {
        pca.project (cloud.points.size(i), projected);
        pca.reconstruct (projected, reconstructed);
    }

}
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    
    // Initiate a new ROS node named "talker"
    ros::init(argc, argv, "lane_detection_pca_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/scan", 1000, getOrientation);
    return 0;
    ros::spin();
}
```

When try to build with catkin_make I got this error:

```
lane_detection_pca_node.cpp:37:41:error: no matching function for call to std::vector<geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void> > > >::size(size_t&)’
   37 |         pca.project (cloud.points.size(i), projected);
```

Any help to fix it?
Another example of using PCA with point clouds will be

```
Eigen::Vector4f pcaCentroid;
pcl::compute3dCentroid(*cloud, pcaCentroid)
...
```

Which one would  be the correct one?

Comment: Std vector doesn't have the method size() with parameters. You likely want `cloud.points[i]`.

Comment: I change and now got this error: lane_detection_pca_node.cpp:38:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘pcl::PCA<pcl::PointXYZ>::project(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void> > >, geometry_msgs::Point32_<std::allocator<void> > >::value_type&, pcl::PointXYZ&)’
   38 |         pca.project (cloud.points[i], projected);

Comment: You have moved forward a bit. Don't guess, read the API manual.

Comment: Which API?You mean the PCL API?

Comment: so the projected cloud is a problem

Comment: ok found out . The problem is that cloud is sensor_msgs::PointCloud cloud, and the  projected us pcl::PointXYZ . so I need pcl::fromROSMsg(cloud, cloud_new). Right?

Comment: Sorry still stuck with this. any help how to solve the  projected one?

Comment: ok solve it with for(size_t i = 0; i < cloud.points.size(); i++)
    {
            pcl::PointXYZ p;
            p.x = cloud.points[i].x;
            p.y = cloud.points[i].y;
            p.z = cloud.points[i].z;

            pca.project (p, (*projected)[i]);
    }